# Blender Python Translate object using three points

Tags: python, scripting

I have a collection of objects that I cycle through with a python script. Each object has six custom properties: OriginX, OriginY, OriginZ, TranslateX, TranslateY, and TranslateZ.
Each property represents a coordinate in X, Y or Z. The first three are 3D points that the object is imported to. The last three are the points I want to translate the object to.

[image]

In the image OriginX is #1, OriginY is #2, and OriginZ is #3. I want to translate #1 to #4 (TranslateX), #2 to #5 (TranslateY) and #3 to #6 (TranslateZ).

In my code I effectively transform (via rotation) the part from point #1 to point #4, but how can I apply a translation with #2 to #5 and #3 to #6? The object do not scale.

In NX I would create a coordinate system (Csys) for each set of three points (Origin and Translate) and do a Csys to Csys transformation. I cannot figure out how to accomplish this in Blender Python.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello ! As a technical standpoint this action is not a pure translation but a transformation (translation + rotation + scale). This is usually done with a Matrix multiplication. If you know the scale is uniform in all axes, you can also decompose it with a translation from 1 to 4 (which is trivial) a rotation from 1-2 to 4-5 (compute the rotational difference and apply it) and a scale from 1-2 to 4-5. If the scale is not uniform you'll have to scale each axis separately but then you'll miss a component in the Y axis. (Unless it stays the same) then you can set it to 1